# Why is this Mono Behavior in the animator?

Tags: unity

I'm looking through the 3D Game Kit from the asset store to accustom myself with the animator, and I'm just wondering what this is referring to.
I was looking into controlling MonoBehaviors through the animation controller the other day and thought I had come to the conclusion that it couldn't be done directly, so what's this?
[image: screenshot of animator]

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @Sidar I'm not stuck on anything, I'm just curious as to what the Mono Behavior is, and why I selected it when I clicked on the Animator Transition

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be covered in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html):

> MonoBehaviour is the base class from which every Unity script derives.

Comment: I think this might be related more specifically to [State Machine Behaviours](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBehaviours.html), as [described in this blog post](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours), for example.

Comment: @DMGregory That's what I would have expected, but if Mono Behaviors and State Machine Behaviors aren't the same thing, what's a Mono Behavior doing in the state machine?